# Is there a way to have a background task written in Python listen for a defined keystroke to set the mouse cursor to center of any focused window?

Tags: python, events, background-process, event-listener, keyboard-events

In other words no matter what program I'm running I want to be able to hit (for example) F7 and have the mouse pointer jump to center of the screen.

I'm using Windows 10 and Linux so either solution would be great. I don't really need the code just need to know if it is possible. I know there are mouse jiggler programs that seem to do something along those lines.

I have been able to do this in Python in a program but it only does this while THAT program is running and has focus.
I have dabbled with ctypes, etc. But I don't know how to make it a background task.
Thanks for any help or direction in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using `pynput` and `pyautogui`. I've tried this code in Mac (and I needed to update some Security settings in my computer in order to run it) so I'm not sure about how it works in Ubuntu. But it'll be a good start point for you...

```
import pyautogui
import pynput.mouse
import pynput.keyboard

def center_mouse_on_press(key):
    if key == pynput.keyboard.Key.f7:
        screen_width, screen_height = pyautogui.size()
        center_x, center_y = screen_width / 2, screen_height / 2
        pyautogui.moveTo(center_x, center_y)

keyboard_listener = pynput.keyboard.Listener(on_press=center_mouse_on_press)
keyboard_listener.start()
keyboard_listener.join()
```

Requirements:

```
pip install pynput
pip install pyautogui
```

**NOTE**: Obviously you need to be running your program in order to work but you can run it in background using `tmux`.

Instructions to run in background with tmux:

**Install tmux:** `apt-get install tmux`

**Commands:**

```
tmux new -s keyboard #enter to new tmux session
python main.py #execute the code
ctrl+b d #detach from session
```

Now you can exit your terminal and the code will be remain running in background. I've tested it and it works for me.

If you have doubts about how to use `tmux` check this [cheatsheet](https://tmuxcheatsheet.com/)